# Problema com Widfly

Tags: java, mysql, jsf, java-ee, ejb

estou tendo um erro ao iniciar o projeto livraria com o Widfly 10. Até a parte de conectar com o banco estava funcionando, agr ao conectar com o mysql estou tendo problemas.

Já criei o banco de dados.
Coloquei os arquivos de module e o jar no dir : C:\wildfly-10.1.0.Final\modules\system\layers\base\com\mysql\main
Alterei o standalone.xml :

```
            <datasources>
            <datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS" pool-name="ExampleDS" enabled="true" use-java-context="true">
                <connection-url>jdbc:h2:mem:test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE</connection-url>
                <driver>h2</driver>
                <security>
                    <user-name>root</user-name>
                    <password>masterkey</password>
                </security>
            </datasource>
            <datasource jndi-name="java:/livrariaDS" pool-name="livrariaDS" enabled="true" use-java-context="true">
                <connection-url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/livraria</connection-url>
                <driver>com.mysql</driver>
                <pool>
                    <min-pool-size>10</min-pool-size>
                    <max-pool-size>100</max-pool-size>
                    <prefill>true</prefill>
                </pool>
                <security>
                    <user-name>root</user-name>
                    <password>masterkey</password>
                </security>
            </datasource>
            <drivers>
                <driver name="h2" module="com.h2database.h2">
                    <xa-datasource-class>org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource</xa-datasource-class>
                </driver>
                <driver name="com.mysql" module="com.mysql">
                    <xa-datasource-class>com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlXADataSource</xa-datasource-class>
                </driver>
            </drivers>
        </datasources>
```

Alterei o persistence.xml na pasta META-INF:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
version="2.0">

<persistence-unit name="livraria">

    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <jta-data-source>java:/livrariaDS</jta-data-source>

    <class>br.com.caelum.livraria.modelo.Autor</class>
    <class>br.com.caelum.livraria.modelo.Livro</class>
    <class>br.com.caelum.livraria.modelo.Usuario</class>

    <properties>

        <!-- Configuracoes especificas do Hibernate -->
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect" />
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />

    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

Já tentei limpar a pasta deployments, re-instalar o mysql, remover e adc dnovo o projeto ao widfly e nada. Se alguém puder me ajudar, segue abaixo o erro:

```
20:21:44,816 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] 

(ServerService Thread Pool -- 33) WFLYJCA0005: Deploying non-JDBC-compliant driver class com.mysql.jdbc.Driver (version 5.1)
20:21:44,859 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.io] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 37) WFLYIO001: Worker 'default' has auto-configured to 8 core threads with 64 task threads based on your 4 available processors
20:21:44,870 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYJCA0009: Starting JCA Subsystem (WildFly/IronJacamar 1.3.4.Final)
20:21:44,901 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYJCA0018: Started Driver service with driver-name = h2
20:21:44,902 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYJCA0018: Started Driver service with driver-name = com.mysql
20:21:44,906 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 38) WFLYCLINF0001: Activating Infinispan subsystem.
20:21:44,920 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYUT0003: Undertow 1.4.0.Final starting
20:21:44,920 WARN  [org.jboss.as.txn] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 54) WFLYTX0013: Node identifier property is set to the default value. Please make sure it is unique.
20:21:44,931 INFO  [org.jboss.as.webservices] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 56) WFLYWS0002: Activating WebServices Extension
20:21:44,932 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 46) WFLYNAM0001: Activating Naming Subsystem
20:21:44,941 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jsf] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 44) WFLYJSF0007: Activated the following JSF Implementations: [main]
20:21:45,059 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYNAM0003: Starting Naming Service
20:21:45,061 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 53) WFLYSEC0002: Activating Security Subsystem
20:21:45,063 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYSEC0001: Current PicketBox version=4.9.6.Final
20:21:45,090 INFO  [org.jboss.as.mail.extension] (MSC service thread 1-5) WFLYMAIL0001: Bound mail session [java:jboss/mail/Default]
20:21:45,102 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYEJB0482: Strict pool mdb-strict-max-pool is using a max instance size of 16 (per class), which is derived from the number of CPUs on this host.
20:21:45,102 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYEJB0481: Strict pool slsb-strict-max-pool is using a max instance size of 64 (per class), which is derived from thread worker pool sizing.
20:21:45,154 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 55) WFLYUT0014: Creating file handler for path 'C:\wildfly-10.1.0.Final/welcome-content' with options [directory-listing: 'false', follow-symlink: 'false', case-sensitive: 'true', safe-symlink-paths: '[]']
20:21:45,297 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYUT0012: Started server default-server.
20:21:45,300 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-5) WFLYUT0018: Host default-host starting
20:21:45,325 INFO  [org.jboss.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBoss Remoting version 4.0.21.Final
20:21:45,362 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYUT0006: Undertow HTTP listener default listening on 127.0.0.1:8080
20:21:45,616 WARN  [org.jboss.as.domain.management.security] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYDM0111: Keystore C:\wildfly-10.1.0.Final\standalone\configuration\application.keystore not found, it will be auto generated on first use with a self signed certificate for host localhost
20:21:45,646 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYDS0013: Started FileSystemDeploymentService for directory C:\wildfly-10.1.0.Final\standalone\deployments
20:21:45,667 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYSRV0027: Starting deployment of "livraria.war" (runtime-name: "livraria.war")
20:21:45,712 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-5) WFLYJCA0001: Bound data source [java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS]
20:21:45,714 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-5) WFLYJCA0001: Bound data source [java:/livrariaDS]
20:21:45,866 INFO  [org.infinispan.factories.GlobalComponentRegistry] (MSC service thread 1-7) ISPN000128: Infinispan version: Infinispan 'Chakra' 8.2.4.Final
20:21:45,950 INFO  [org.infinispan.configuration.cache.EvictionConfigurationBuilder] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 61) ISPN000152: Passivation configured without an eviction policy being selected. Only manually evicted entities will be passivated.
20:21:45,951 INFO  [org.infinispan.configuration.cache.EvictionConfigurationBuilder] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 61) ISPN000152: Passivation configured without an eviction policy being selected. Only manually evicted entities will be passivated.
20:21:45,950 INFO  [org.infinispan.configuration.cache.EvictionConfigurationBuilder] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 59) ISPN000152: Passivation configured without an eviction policy being selected. Only manually evicted entities will be passivated.
20:21:45,963 INFO  [org.infinispan.configuration.cache.EvictionConfigurationBuilder] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 58) ISPN000152: Passivation configured without an eviction policy being selected. Only manually evicted entities will be passivated.
20:21:45,964 INFO  [org.infinispan.configuration.cache.EvictionConfigurationBuilder] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 58) ISPN000152: Passivation configured without an eviction policy being selected. Only manually evicted entities will be passivated.
20:21:45,964 INFO  [org.infinispan.configuration.cache.EvictionConfigurationBuilder] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 59) ISPN000152: Passivation configured without an eviction policy being selected. Only manually evicted entities will be passivated.
20:21:46,448 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-5) WFLYUT0006: Undertow HTTPS listener https listening on 127.0.0.1:8443
20:21:46,510 INFO  [org.jboss.ws.common.management] (MSC service thread 1-5) JBWS022052: Starting JBossWS 5.1.5.Final (Apache CXF 3.1.6) 
20:21:47,096 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYWELD0003: Processing weld deployment livraria.war
20:21:47,136 INFO  [org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.Version] (MSC service thread 1-6) HV000001: Hibernate Validator 5.2.4.Final
20:21:47,190 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYEJB0473: JNDI bindings for session bean named 'LivroDao' in deployment unit 'deployment "livraria.war"' are as follows:

    java:global/livraria/LivroDao!br.com.caelum.livraria.dao.LivroDao
    java:app/livraria/LivroDao!br.com.caelum.livraria.dao.LivroDao
    java:module/LivroDao!br.com.caelum.livraria.dao.LivroDao
    java:global/livraria/LivroDao
    java:app/livraria/LivroDao
    java:module/LivroDao

20:21:47,190 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYEJB0473: JNDI bindings for session bean named 'Banco' in deployment unit 'deployment "livraria.war"' are as follows:

    java:global/livraria/Banco!br.com.caelum.livraria.dao.Banco
    java:app/livraria/Banco!br.com.caelum.livraria.dao.Banco
    java:module/Banco!br.com.caelum.livraria.dao.Banco
    java:global/livraria/Banco
    java:app/livraria/Banco
    java:module/Banco

20:21:47,190 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYEJB0473: JNDI bindings for session bean named 'AutorDao' in deployment unit 'deployment "livraria.war"' are as follows:

    java:global/livraria/AutorDao!br.com.caelum.livraria.dao.AutorDao
    java:app/livraria/AutorDao!br.com.caelum.livraria.dao.AutorDao
    java:module/AutorDao!br.com.caelum.livraria.dao.AutorDao
    java:global/livraria/AutorDao
    java:app/livraria/AutorDao
    java:module/AutorDao

20:21:47,191 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYEJB0473: JNDI bindings for session bean named 'UsuarioDao' in deployment unit 'deployment "livraria.war"' are as follows:

    java:global/livraria/UsuarioDao!br.com.caelum.livraria.dao.UsuarioDao
    java:app/livraria/UsuarioDao!br.com.caelum.livraria.dao.UsuarioDao
    java:module/UsuarioDao!br.com.caelum.livraria.dao.UsuarioDao
    java:global/livraria/UsuarioDao
    java:app/livraria/UsuarioDao
    java:module/UsuarioDao

20:21:47,335 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-6) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."livraria.war".INSTALL: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."livraria.war".INSTALL: WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase INSTALL of deployment "livraria.war"
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:154)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1948)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1881)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: WFLYEE0041: Component class br.com.caelum.livraria.dao.AutorDao for component AutorDao has errors: 
WFLYJPA0033: Can't find a persistence unit named livraria in deployment "livraria.war"
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.ModuleJndiBindingProcessor$1.handle(ModuleJndiBindingProcessor.java:157)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ClassDescriptionTraversal.run(ClassDescriptionTraversal.java:54)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.ModuleJndiBindingProcessor.processClassConfigurations(ModuleJndiBindingProcessor.java:186)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.ModuleJndiBindingProcessor.deploy(ModuleJndiBindingProcessor.java:143)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:147)
    ... 5 more

20:21:47,344 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "livraria.war")]) - failure description: {
    "WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"livraria.war\".INSTALL" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit.\"livraria.war\".INSTALL: WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase INSTALL of deployment \"livraria.war\"
    Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: WFLYEE0041: Component class br.com.caelum.livraria.dao.AutorDao for component AutorDao has errors: 
WFLYJPA0033: Can't find a persistence unit named livraria in deployment \"livraria.war\""},
    "WFLYCTL0412: Required services that are not installed:" => [
        "jboss.deployment.unit.\"livraria.war\".beanmanager",
        "jboss.deployment.unit.\"livraria.war\".INSTALL"
    ],
    "WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => [
        "jboss.deployment.unit.\"livraria.war\".batch.environment is missing [jboss.deployment.unit.\"livraria.war\".beanmanager]",
        "jboss.deployment.unit.\"livraria.war\".weld.weldClassIntrospector is missing [jboss.deployment.unit.\"livraria.war\".beanmanager]"
    ]
}
20:21:47,389 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 34) WFLYSRV0010: Deployed "livraria.war" (runtime-name : "livraria.war")
20:21:47,397 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0183: Service status report
WFLYCTL0184:    New missing/unsatisfied dependencies:
      service jboss.deployment.unit."livraria.war".beanmanager (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."livraria.war".batch.environment, service jboss.deployment.unit."livraria.war".weld.weldClassIntrospector] 
WFLYCTL0186:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.deployment.unit."livraria.war".INSTALL: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."livraria.war".INSTALL: WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase INSTALL of deployment "livraria.war"

20:21:47,478 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0060: Http management interface listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990/management
20:21:47,478 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0051: Admin console listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990
20:21:47,479 ERROR [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0026: WildFly Full 10.1.0.Final (WildFly Core 2.2.0.Final) started (with errors) in 4295ms - Started 368 of 616 services (3 services failed or missing dependencies, 396 services are lazy, passive or on-demand)
20:21:47,511 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYSRV0028: Stopped deployment livraria.war (runtime-name: livraria.war) in 7ms
20:21:47,559 WARN  [org.jboss.as.controller] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) WFLYCTL0357: Notification of type deployment-undeployed is not described for the resource at the address []
20:21:47,560 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) WFLYSRV0009: Undeployed "livraria.war" (runtime-name: "livraria.war")
20:21:47,560 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) WFLYCTL0183: Service status report
WFLYCTL0186:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.deployment.unit."livraria.war".INSTALL

20:21:52,432 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) WFLYDS0004: Found livraria.war in deployment directory. To trigger deployment create a file called livraria.war.dodeploy
```

Comment: Olá Rafael, bem-vindo ao PT.StackOverflow! Você está conseguindo seu datasource ao Mysql pelo painel de controle do WildFly?